# I want to pass enhanced for loop dynamic values in SQL Query?

Tags: java, sql

I'm having one List Collection values like below and I want while retrieving value should be pass in sql query.

```
List obl = new ArrayList();
obs.add(1234);
obs.add(1235);
obs.add(1236);
obs.add(1237);
```

Here problem is only first value getting passed? I want all values should passed and appropriate output should get.

```
for(Object obls:obl){
    String sql2 ="select Student_Name,FeesHead,Amount,BankName,YearID from test where ReceiptNo = '"+obls+"'";                                             
    stat =  con.prepareStatement(sql2);
    rs=stat.executeQuery();
    rs.next();
    String StudentName  = rs.getString(1);
    String FeesHead     = rs.getString(2);
    String Amount       = rs.getString(3);
    String BankName     = rs.getString(4);
    Integer LYearID     = rs.getInt(5);
    System.out.println("Fees Head"+FeesHead);
    System.out.println("Amount"+Amount);
    System.out.println("Bank Name"+BankName);
    System.out.println("Year ID --"+LYearID);
}
```

Comment: typo: firts row obl  instead of obs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to what has already been said:
I suggest you use if(rs.next()) instead of while(rs.next()) if you know you are going to get at most one result per query.
Also, after printing out the Year ID, you may add this:
stat.clearParameters().
Although not strictly necessary in this situation, its wouldn't hurt (you can read up on clearParameters to get a better idea of its use).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 String sql2 = "select Student_Name,FeesHead,Amount,BankName,YearID from test where ReceiptNo = ?";
PreparedStatement stat = con.prepareStatement(sql2);

try {
   for(Object obl:obl){
   stat.setObject(1, obl);
   rs=stat.executeQuery();
   rs.next();
   String StudentName  = rs.getString(1);
   String FeesHead     = rs.getString(2);
   String Amount       = rs.getString(3);
   String BankName     = rs.getString(4);
   Integer LYearID     = rs.getInt(5);
   System.out.println("Fees Head"+FeesHead);
   System.out.println("Amount"+Amount);
   System.out.println("Bank Name"+BankName);
   System.out.println("Year ID --"+LYearID);
   }
} finally {
    if (stat != null) {
        stat.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("(");
for (Object o : obl) {
    sb.append("'").append(o).append("',");
}
sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
sb.append(")");

String sql2 ="select Student_Name,FeesHead,Amount,BankName,YearID from test where ReceiptNo in " + sb.toString();
Statement stat = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
ResultSet rs=stat.executeQuery(sql2);
while (rs.next()) {
    String StudentName  = rs.getString(1);
    String FeesHead     = rs.getString(2);
    String Amount       = rs.getString(3);
    String BankName     = rs.getString(4);
    Integer LYearID     = rs.getInt(5);
    System.out.println("Fees Head"+FeesHead);
    System.out.println("Amount"+Amount);
    System.out.println("Bank Name"+BankName);
    System.out.println("Year ID --"+LYearID);
}
stat.close();
rs.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(Object obls:obl){
        String sql2 ="select Student_Name,FeesHead,Amount,BankName,YearID from test where ReceiptNo = '"+obls+"'";                                             
        stat =  con.prepareStatement(sql2);
        rs=stat.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
{
        String StudentName  = rs.getString(1);
        String FeesHead     = rs.getString(2);
        String Amount       = rs.getString(3);
        String BankName     = rs.getString(4);
        Integer LYearID     = rs.getInt(5);
        System.out.println("Fees Head"+FeesHead);
        System.out.println("Amount"+Amount);
        System.out.println("Bank Name"+BankName);
        System.out.println("Year ID --"+LYearID);
}
    }
```